# Button Not aligning in center

Tags: html, css

I somehow managed to make the input box responsive but the button is not being aligned in center

here is the css code

```
    .webdesigntuts-workshop button {
  background: linear-gradient(#333, #222);
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Cabin", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
  max-width:120px;
  float:center;

}
```

Here is the whole Codepen link

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XZrqzZ

Comment: There is no `float:center;`

Comment: And you should post your complete code (including HTML) - one CSS rule alone is not enough to describe a problem

Comment: ah sry about that float:center; and the code is big thats why i included a codepen.io link

Comment: @jackwhacky the button in your link seems to be centered, no matter the width of the window!

Comment: Next time, include only the relevant data to the question. There's no need to read through your font design

Answer (score 0):

Your code is messy, to much, in fact. Yet, the problem is not the button, but the input. The margins in the input is pushing it out of the screen because you have the width to 100%. So, the input take 100% of the screen *plus* the margin, pushing it out of the layout intended.

Try this in your css:

```
.webdesigntuts-workshop input{
  margin: 0;   /* Put 0 */
  width: 100%;
}

.webdesigntuts-workshop button {
  margin: 0 auto;   /* Add this */
}
```